# Duda sobre guardar una imagen en base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, imagen

Tengo una duda sobre guardar una imagen en una base de datos, en especifico mysql, mi duda es qué ocuparía mas espacio en el servidor, guardar los bytes de la imagen en un campo de tipo `bytes` o guardar la imagen en un directorio especifico y luego ese directorio guardarlo en un campo de tipo `varchar`, para luego así saber a que directorio poder ir a buscar la imagen y mostrarla

Si guardo los bytes de la imagen así:
digamos que tengo esta tabla

```
   int  bytes
   id | imagen
   ---------------
   1  | bytes[ ]
   2  | bytes[ ]
```

pienso que si lo guardo de esta forma trabajara mas el server ya que para guardarlo primero tendría que obtener array de bytes de la imagen y posteriormente realizar el insert del array, luego para poder visualizar la imagen abría que reconstruirla.

ahora bien si lo guardo de esta forma:

```
 int  varchar
 id | imagen
 ---------------
 1  | mipagina.com/imagenes/test.png
 2  | mipagina.com/imagenes/test1.png
```

ocuparía menos espacio en la base de datos pero la imagen que se guardaría en el directorio especifico, el espacio en disco iría aumentando más rápido ya que hay imágenes que pesa mas de 1MB.

Que es mas factible? Alguien que comparta su experiencia, agradecería sus opiniones. Saludos.

Comment: Generalmente, se guarda en un campo de texto la ruta a la imagen. De esta forma, evitas saturar el servidor de base de datos con archivos que pueden ser grandes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Te recomiendo leer [MySQL Binary Storage using BLOB VS OS File System: large files, large quantities, large problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654004/mysql-binary-storage-using-blob-vs-os-file-system-large-files-large-quantities) y [To Do or Not to Do: Store Images in a Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815626/to-do-or-not-to-do-store-images-in-a-database)

En resumen y como la mayoría de los casos en informática, depende de tu sistema. Si vas a guardar 100 imágenes de 1MB y tu sistema no crecerá en el tiempo de forma exponencial, guardalas en la BD, lo cual te ayudará a que el desarrollo sea más rápido. Ahora, si tu sistema explotará en usuarios, acceso a las imágenes y/o cantidad de imágenes, es recomendable guardar solo los paths de estas en BD, así te evitas que tu BD crezca de forma no controlada, además, si necesitas hacer algun post-procesamiento a tus imágenes, solo programas un script que lea desde un directorio y no tienes que estar pegándole a la BD una y otras vez. Entre otras cosas a considerar, es que actualmente el storage en estos momentos es casi marginal a nivel de costes, por lo que podrías levantar un servicio distribuido para tus imágenes en varios servers, resiliente, con bajos tiempos de carga, distribuido y hermoso.

Ahora, personalmente hablando, aunque tu sistema sea grande o pequeño, no recomiendo bajo ningún caso guardar las imágenes en la BD. ¿Por qué?

- Hacer los backups es más costoso: escribes MUCHOS más bytes
- Al escribir muchos más bytes, y las imágenes ser binarias y estar comprimidas, ejecutar un tar.gzip/xz/bzip2/etc, hará que tu archivo de backup no comprima eficientemente y tendrás que mover muchos más datos de para hacer un backup.
- Vamos! la BD es para guardar DATOS!
- ¿Como accedes de forma fácil a tu imagen? programando un endpoint en algún lenguaje, el cual debe:

  1. Conectarse a la BD
  2. Consultar el dato BLOB
  3. Deducir el mimetype de tu imagen (vamos, este podría estar guardado, no?)
  4. Escribir el contenido de tu imagen
  5. Cerrar la conexión

  Si los guardas en un directorio, puedes configurar tu webserver (Nginx por ejemplo), para que todas que tengas un subdomino específico, el cual sirva las imágenes en el directorio en el que están, gracias a lo cual puedes posteriormente, mover tus imágenes a otro servidor y hacer balanceo de carga

Recuerda, en informática, la máxima es siempre: *"Divide y vencerás"*.

Comment: Gracias Pablo me has dado un mejor panorama a la respuesta de mi duda.

Answer (score 0):

Guardar los bytes en la base de datos es lo menos costoso.

De la segunda forma, además del espacio en disco que ocupas, tenes el tiempo de búsqueda y a eso tenes que sumarle el tiempo de acceso al disco y la latencia del mismo.

Ni hablar si tenes que aplicar una política de backup...es más fácil y rápido hacer un backup de una base de datos.

Espero que te sea ayuda.

Saludos

Comment: ¡Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! ☺ No olvides visitar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más acerca de este sitio. Cuando dices `"Guardar los bytes en la base de datos es lo menos costoso"`, ¿crees que puedas proporcionar alguna referencia confiable y comprobable que pueda dar soporte a tal declaración? El siguiente enlace puede ser de utilidad: [*¿Como escribo una buena respuesta?*](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)